# TokenError on line 10.. but there are only 9 lines of code

Tags: python, token

As far as I'm aware, there are no bugs in this code, but the compiler is telling me there is an error on line ten out of 9 lines of code. I just want to know if the compiler is buggered, or if there is a bug and I just don't see it.

```
string=""
index=0

def replaceatindex(string,index):
    firsthalf=string[:(index-1)]
    lasthalf=string[(index+1):]
    print firsthalf+"-"+lasthalf
stringinput=input("Give me a string:  ")
indexinput=int(input("Give man index:  ")
```

Comment: TokenError: EOF in multi-line statement on line 10

Comment: Your final line is missing a closing paren/bracket. The compiler is looking for that on line 10.

Comment: I can't facepalm hard enough.

Comment: It's ok, man. We all have been there.